# Difference between JMeter - HTML Dashboard Report(Response Times Over Time) and Response Times Over Time Listener

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have observed difference between JMeter - HTML Dashboard Report(Response Times Over Time)  and Response Times Over Time Listener.
I am using JMeter version 3.3
HTML Dashboard Report shows Peak value of Response time = 28455 ms @ 11:33:00 whereas Response Times Over Time Listener shows peak value of Response time = 45803.6 ms @ 00:00:52.

Both the HTML report and Listener are generated using same result.csv file.

Can anyone please help me understand this. Please correct me if I am understanding this incorrectly.

[image: screenshot of HTML report and listener]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to say what is the cause without seeing the configuration of the Response Times Over Time listener and HTML Reporting Dashboard.

Most likely your dashboard is [configured](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration) in the way that it "masks" this spike due to high granularity compared with relatively low test duration (1.5 minutes)

One more place where the differences could be is "Type of Graph" setting of the [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/)

[image: JMeter Response Times Over Time]

Similarly configured graphs generation should produce similar graphs on the same data (unless there is a bug)

---

And finally make sure that you use:

1. Latest version of the Response Times over Time plugin (you can check for/install updates using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))
2. Latest version of JMeter ([JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) as of now)

Comment: Thanks for the above information @ Dimitri T but I have latest version of Jars for Response Times over Time plugin (version 2.0) and I have not altered any of the configuration for dashboard. Also Checked with "Type of Graph" setting of the Response Times Over Time earlier as well as after reading this answer but I have got the exact graph values.